# Bash Terminal Redirect to another Terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, redirect, pipe

I have netcat port listening on port 1501 and I wanna pipe the recieved input on that port to a new terminal window. I know this is a bad idea because basically anyone on that port can control the machine but I want to figure out if its possible to do. Anyone know how. I have tried this so far.

nc -l 1500 | xterm
or 
nc -l 1500 | xterm -e "NAMEOFWINDOW"

also tried redirecting to gnome-terminal in a simpliar fashion. I can  do

nc -l 1500 | grep "SOMEKEYWORD" successfully.

Any ideas?
-TJ

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.  The first is that `xterm` and `gnome-terminal` aren't the program that provide the prompt and accept commands - they are just a way of connecting your keyboard and screen to that program, which is your shell (typically `/bin/bash`).  So, it's actually `bash` that you want to connect to netcat.

Secondly, you need more than just a one-directional pipe, which is what you get with `|`.  If you use:

```
nc -l -p 1500 | /bin/bash
```

then you will only have a pipe *from* the user *to* `bash` - they'll be able to give input, but won't see any output.  Alternatively, if you do:

```
/bin/bash | nc -l -p 1500
```

then the opposite will apply - you'll only have a pipe *to* the user *from* `bash`.  The user will see output from `bash`, but won't be able give any input.

Luckily, netcat supports an option to create a bidirectional pipe (actually, two pipes) to another command:

```
nc -l -p 1500 -e /bin/bash
```

This will do what you want - but note that `bash` will not display a prompt, since it will be running in "non-interactive" mode.

Oh, and one more thing - yes, this is a *really* bad idea.

Comment: Lol I know its a idiotic idea more for the interest of can it be done. Thanks great response btw. Awesome explanation detail overall :) good job.

Comment: Actually Tried this now. -e isn't a recognized switch Im using ubuntu si it my version of netcat or am i missing something?

Comment: @TJ Pavlu: Oh yeah, by default Ubuntu installs a gimped netcat, you need the `netcat-traditional` package, which supplies `nc.traditional`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible this way, as `xterm` does not accept input on *stdin*, it catches keyboard input directly.

There are two alternatives:

- use `bash` instead of xterm: `nc -l 1500 | bash` in a xterm
- use `xterm`s -S option, but you need to attach the netcat to a pseudo tty before, an then attach the xterm to the pseudo terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tee` to redirect the output to temporary file and then `tail --follow=name --retry` in another terminal.

```
nc -l 1500 | tee /tmp/file.txt
```

and of course:

```
tail --follow=name --retry /tmp/file.txt
```

This way you can do `rm -f /tmp/file.txt` via cron job without the `tail` command being interrupted.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question.